# Addition of default argument makes this constructor a default constructor

Tags: c++, arguments, default

I am trying to run the following simple code but keep getting:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Could some please explain to me what this means?

Code:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream in;
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    string s = GetLine();
    in.open(s.c_str());
    if (in.fail())
        Error("Error your file was not found");
    return 0;
}
```

Error comes from the following:

```
ErrorException::ErrorException(string m="unspecified custom error") 
: msg(m) {
}

ErrorException::~ErrorException() throw() {}

const char* ErrorException::what() const throw() {
return this->msg.c_str(); 
}

void Error(string str) {
    ErrorException err(str);
    throw err;
}
```

I should be getting back the error message that I specified, but I don't; can anyone see why?

Comment: What does this have to do with your question title?

Comment: What do you mean by "getting back the error message"? Where are you expecting the error message to go?

Answer (score 1):

You throw an exception you don't catch. That terminates the program. You have no code to receive the error message, print it, or do anything like that. If you want to catch the exception, use a `try`/`catch` block. In the `catch` portion, you can do whatever you want with the error message.

Try something like:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream in;
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    string s = GetLine();
    try
    {
       in.open(s.c_str());
       if (in.fail())
           Error("Error your file was not found");
    }
    catch (ErrorException& e)
    {
       cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was expecting that if it couldnt find the file, it would tell the user "Error your file was not found".

Comment: @BenjaminRCBell: What is the "it" that you were thinking would tell the user something? Your code doesn't contain anything that would tell the user that. (And how would it tell the user *anything*? How does it know how to reach the user? Should it pop up a window? Send an email? Write to `stderr`? Or what?)

Comment: Just to return the default error or my specified error msg to the console. This code is from an online university course. The error function was rewritten by someone trying to reconstitute the header package provided by the University (no longer available online). These headers are provided to aid students in the learning process without dealing with certain things that tend to be more complex.
When I say it I guess I am referring to in.open(s.c_str());

Comment: @BenjaminRCBell: Nothing has any idea that it's an error message or that it should be sent to the console. The compiler knows there's a function called `what` that returns that string. But there's no code anywhere to suggest that it would be useful to output that string to the console. If you want it, you need to write it. There is nothing magical about naming a method `what`. You still have to call it if you want it to be invoked.